# Stream to populate 2D array of doubles

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following loop that I would like to convert to a parallel stream. Note that `mbbVariance` and `nbbVariance` both return a `double`.

```
double[][] outMBB = new double[rows][maxBlockSize];
double[][] outNBB = new double[rows][maxBlockSize];

for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
       for (int m = 0; m < maxBlockSize; m++) {
                outMBB[j][m] = mbbVariance(timeSeries[j], m + 1, alpha);
                outNBB[j][m] = nbbVariance(timeSeries[j], m + 1, alpha);
       }
}
```

My best attempt was

```
double[][] outMBB = IntStream.range(0, rows)
                                     .parallel()
                                     .mapToDouble(j -> (
                                                IntStream.range(0, maxBlockSize)
                                                         .mapToDouble(m -> mbbVariance(timeSeries[j], m + 1, alpha))
                                                         .toArray(double[]::new)
                                                        )
                                                )
                                      .toArray(double[][]::new);

double[][] outNBB = IntStream.range(0, rows)
                                     .parallel()
                                     .mapToDouble(j -> (
                                                IntStream.range(0, maxBlockSize)
                                                         .mapToDouble(m -> nbbVariance(timeSeries[j], m + 1, alpha))
                                                         .toArray(double[]::new)
                                                        )
                                                )
                                      .toArray(double[][]::new);
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really not a pro with streams, this solution is more of a starting point than a polished product.

```
double[][] outMBB = new double[rows][maxBlockSize];
double[][] outNBB = new double[rows][maxBlockSize];
IntStream.range(0, rows).forEach(i -> IntStream.range(0, maxBlockSize).forEach(
        m -> {  outFSMBB[j][m] = mbbVariance(timeSeries[j], m + 1, alpha);
                outFSNBB[j][m] = nbbVariance(timeSeries[j], m + 1, alpha);
        }));
```

This solution is more of a simulation of what you did with loops than a real utilisation of what streams are capable of.

Comment: No problem. You can stack as many forEach's inside each-other as you want. Any time you fail to use a collector at the end of your stream, you can try it with a forEach: For example you can use add() to an existing list instead of collected(Collctors.toList()). Often times it is less clean though.

Answer (score 1):

You were really close with your first attempt.

```
int rows = 4;
int columns = 5;
double[][] outNBB = IntStream.range(0, rows).mapToObj( 
            j -> IntStream.range(0, columns).mapToDouble(
                m -> Math.random()
            ).toArray()
        ).toArray(double[][]::new);
```

You pretty much just needed to `mapToObj` and not `mapToDouble` since a double[][] is actually an array of objects where each object is a double[].

Comment: Do you use mapToDouble(...) because you use the primite datatype? If you used Double, could you also just use map(...)?

Comment: Right, if you used map and Double then you would get a `Double[][]` which you should probably use a List at that point.